# Rのパッケージインストール時のエラー

Tags: r

Rstudioでパッケージを何かインストールしようとすると毎回

```
Error in install.packages : error reading from connection
```

というエラーが表示されます。
何度かR, R studio, rtoolsをダウンロードしなおしました。
原因不明です・・既にほかのアプリも入れているPCなので、あまりクリーニングはしたくありません。

Rで、普通にタブのところからCRANミラーサイトの設定をしようとすると

```
> chooseCRANmirror()
 警告:  failed to download mirrors file ( URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv' を開けません ); using local file 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
 警告メッセージ: 
 download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) で: 
  URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'HTTP response code said error'
>
```

と表示されます。

何か原因の分かる方いらっしゃいませんか？
会社のPCなので、PC自体のクリーンはほぼできないと思ってほしいです。

また、ファイヤーウォールを突破してないのかとおもって、

```
> proxy="http://会社のIPアドレス:ポート番号/"
> Sys.setenv("ftp_proxy" = proxy)
> Sys.setenv("http_proxy" = proxy)
> Sys.setenv("https_proxy" = proxy)
```

と入力したあと、

```
> curlGetHeaders("https://google.com/")
```

と入力して返り値が200になることを確認したので、おそらく突破しています。

Comment: そちらの会社のネットワークでフィルタリングされているのではありませんか？ 管理者の方に問い合わせてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: ネットワークのファイヤーウォールを突破してるか確認しましたが、突破できているようでした・・

Comment: 手元の PC から https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv に対して HTTP GET を行うと問題なく取得できます。`curlGetHeaders("https://cran.r-project.org/")` の場合は HTTP response status は 200 になりますか？

Comment: cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csvっていうリンク押すだけで大丈夫でしたか？それだと問題なくダウンロードできました。curlGetHeaders("https://cran.r-project.org/")を打ち込みましたが、Error in curlGetHeaders("https://cran.r-project.org/") : 
  libcurl error code 56:
 Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECTというエラーがでました。

Comment: ステータスコード407は 「Proxy Authentication Required」という意味で、認証を要求しています。おそらく、そのプロキシはホワイトリスト形式になっているのではないでしょうか。google へのアクセスは許可するが、許可リストに載っていない cran.r-project.org は拒否されているのかもしれません。やはり、プロキシサーバを管理している部署に問い合わせる方がよいでしょう。

Comment: 一番初めにRをインストールしたときは普通にパッケージインストールできたんですが、rglのライブラリを開こうとしたとき、xfunというパッケージがインストールできていないと表示されて、その時からアンインストールしたりインストールしなおしたりしていたらこうなりました・・。再インストールを繰り返すうちに途中から認証が必要になることがあるんでしょうか？

Comment: 私には全くもって判らないことです。。。社内の誰かに聞いてみて下さい。

Comment: 色々とお返事いただきありがとうございました。一番初めにRをインストールしたときはうまくいったと言いましたが、思い返してみると、その時は在宅で少し違う方法でネットワークに接続していました。なので再度家のネットワークにつないでダウンロードをしてみると、全部インストールできました！ただ、やはりできないのが、library(rgl)です・・これだけが"R Session Aborted　R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated　Start New Session"というエラーが出ます。何か原因わかったりしますか・・？

Comment: install.packages("rgl", dependencies=TRUE)をして、依存先のファイル？までインストールしましたが同じエラーがでました・・